# Changing colors along gradients in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I am working on a project that uses a lot of gradients.

I have decided to change all instances of `RGB(255,255,255)` along the gradient to `RGB(245,245,245)` so that when I export with an alpha channel it doesn't map certain parts to transparent.

I used the Recolor Artwork tool in Illustrator to do this, but when I click on the right to tell Recolor what I want the new color to be, it seems to change the original color (on the left) to the new color as well...

So instead of mapping `RGB(255,255,255)` to `RGB(245,245,245)`, it's mapping `RGB(245,245,245)` to `RGB(245,245,245)`!

That is, it's keeping the original color!

What's going on and how do I fix this? Is this a problem because the colors I'm changing are points along a gradient?

This is the Recolor Artwork tool:
[image: Recolor Artwork Tool]

Comment: I'm having trouble following. Please slow down and take into account that no one here knows what features you are using (Color change thing?) and what specific steps you may be taking. Please edit your question and keep in mind, we can't see what you are doing.

Comment: I made some changes. Do you understand better now?

Comment: Not really... I think I would need a screenshot of the recolor window you are seeing. But perhaps someone else will know better.

Comment: Also, what's really bizarre about this is that even though there are instances of ``RGB(255,255,255)`` the Recolor Artwork tool doesn't have that on the list of colors in my image. So I add it to the list. But again, if I tell the left hand side that it's ``RGB(255,255,255)`` and the right side to change it to RGB(245,245,245), it changes both sides to the latter! I'm adding a screenshot of the Recolor Artwork tool in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more of an educated guess based upon my experience....

---

I *think* the issue may be that you are working with, or wanting to change. **white** - `R255/G255/B255`.

By default Recolor Artwork *protects* both white and black and tries to *preserve* those values.

To get around this, you must "un-preserve" white. To do that click the little preference icon in the middle of the Recolor window (circled in green below).

[image]

Then you'll get a pop up which is similar to the image below 
<sup>(Below is from CS6, I can't boot CC020 right now, but it should be very similar)</sup>

[image]

**Untick** `White` and click `OK`. Then try recoloring. That *should* allow you to alter white values.

Note that this option tends to reset, either per use or per document, I haven't watched it close enough to know exactly when it resets. So it's something to be familiar with any time you expect black or white to be altered by the Recolor Artwork dialog.